# Excel - Count Unique and Filtered Values

Tags: excel, unique, countif

I'm trying to create a report to count the number of events based on a few conditions. This is the formula I've came up with so far:

*=SUM(COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!B:B,"202201",'Sheet1'!M:M,{"This is text 1","This is text 2","This is text 3","This is text 4"}))*

The formula above works well counting the total number of events but it doesn't remove the duplicates in column C.

The first condition is to select the period 202201 in column B, select unique event numbers in column C, and then match these events with the text description in column M. Each event in column C has a unique number but it comes with many different asset numbers in column D, which end up duplicating these unique event numbers in column C. In other words, I only need to count the total number of unique events of each period based on the description and without the asset numbers.

This report is pulling data from another tab in the workbook which is also importing filtered data from a different spreadsheet. The goal is to allow the team to simply update the report clicking Refresh All.

Hope it makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Excel's `unique` function doesn't like to be counted does it!  This task is probably better suited to using PowerQuery, but if you're looking for a *one-liner* then you can `concatenate` the columns, filter using `unique` and use `concat` to create one long string of your unique elements.

From here you want to count unique elements for a certain period, denoted by a substring.  One of the easier ways to search the longer string for a substring's occurrences is to note the difference in the length before and after removing the substring using the `substitute` function, and then dividing that difference by the length of the substring.  This is cleaner now that the `let` function exists in Office365.

Putting all this together gives;

```
=LET(str,CONCAT(UNIQUE(CONCATENATE(B:B,M:M))),(LEN(str)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(str,"202204","")))/LEN("220204"))
```

The `CONCAT(UNIQUE(CONCATENATE` creates the long string, and `LET` assigns it the name `str`, and then we use the difference in the length of `str` before and after removing the substring and divide to count how many times 202204 occurs.

If you don't have Office 365, then you need to create the longer string twice, so the formula is a little longer (and slower);

```
=(LEN(CONCAT(UNIQUE(CONCATENATE(B:B,M:M))))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(UNIQUE(CONCATENATE(B:B,M:M))),"202204","")))/LEN("220204")
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to "externalize" conditions - in this case the valid descriptions.

You can use the following formula:

```vb
=LET(filteredList, FILTER(tblData,(COUNTIF(tblFilter[valid Description],tblData[Description]))*(tblData[Date]=[@Date])),
resizedList,FILTER(filteredList,{1,1,1,0}),
uniqueList,UNIQUE(resizedList),
ROWS(uniqueList))
```

`filteredList` returns a list for the according date and the valid descriptions

`resizedList` removes the description column

`uniqueList` can then return the unique values for Date, event, assest (as description is omitted)

Then the number of unique rows is returned.

This is my setting:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution at Excel Forum for my own problem that I would like to share here, although I tried both above which didn't work or were complex to my current skills. I'm thankful for you taking the time to help me.

The formula is:

```
=SUM(SIGN(COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$2000,TEXT('Column Name A'!D2,"yyyymm"),'Column Name B'!$C$2:$C$2000,UNIQUE('Column Name B'!$C$2:$C$2000),'Column Name C'!$M$2:$M$2000,{"This is text 1","This is text 2","This is text 3","This is text 4"})))
```

The column names and other details were changed for privacy reasons but this is the syntax that made more sense to me and has been working well.